# DataTables - createdRow in conjunction with dynamic column hide/unhide

Tags: datatables

I implemented a dynamic column visibility to hide/show columns, e.g. `DT.columns(5).visible(true)` and `DT.columns(5).visible(false)` to show/hide column 5. I also have a callback for `createdRow` which let's say makes a html button out of the text in column 5.

Currently in `createdRow` I check `this.api().columns(5).visible()` and if true then I proceed to do `$('td:eq(5)',row).html('<button>'+data[5]+'</button>')` cell content, and if false then I return because otherwise I'd overwrite the current 5th `<td>` which is not the intended one. But then when I unhide column 5, it comes up as text since I did not run the previous code.

I'd like to be able to run the code and cache the html of the cell in column 5 so that when it's unhidden, it comes up with the intended `<button>`. What's the best way to do that? The `column-visibility` event?

Note that I know I can use the `render: function (...) {}` option for the column, but I do *not* want to use that because it affects the raw data of the table and affects filtering and searching - I want the raw data to remain unaffected, which is why I was using the `createdRow` or `rawCallback` callbacks.

Assume column 5 has `visibile: false` in the `DataTable` initialization object which looks like this:

```
var DT = $('#dt').DataTable({
  ...
  createdRow: function (row, data) {
    if (this.api().column(5).visible()) {
      $('<button>' + data[5] + </button>')
        .appendTo($('td:eq(5)',row).text(''));
  }
);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Look into using columnDefs and the 'render' function instead...

```
var DT = $('#dt').DataTable({
    ...
  "columnDefs":[
            {
            'targets':[0],
            'visible':false,
            'render':function(data, type, row, meta){
                 ...
             }
    ]
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data